# Using a list of lists to filter a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have two lists of lists, one that includes all records e.g. `[['eggs', 'milk', 'butter'], ['ham', 'spam', 'milk'], ['cereal', 'skittles']]` and one that contains rules `[['milk', 'eggs'], ['milk','ham']]`.

I'm trying to filter records by the list_of_rules, however, I want to capture `[['eggs', 'milk', 'butter'], ['ham', 'spam', 'milk']]` despite it not exactly matching `[['milk', 'eggs'], ['milk','ham']]` order and extra items wise.

```
records = [['eggs', 'milk', 'butter'], ['ham', 'spam', 'milk'], ['cereal', 'skittles']]

list_of_rules = [['milk', 'eggs'], ['milk','ham']]

# this list comprehension only filters for exact matches

results = [[x for x in L if x in records] for L in list_of_rules] 


# expected output

print(results)
>>[['eggs', 'milk', 'butter'], ['ham', 'spam', 'milk']]
```

Any and all recommendations very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this list comprehension:

```
records = [['eggs', 'milk', 'butter'], ['ham', 'spam', 'milk'], ['cereal', 'skittles']]

list_of_rules = [['milk', 'eggs'], ['milk','ham']]

results = [L for L in records if any(set(R).issubset(L) for R in list_of_rules)]

print(results) # => [['eggs', 'milk', 'butter'], ['ham', 'spam', 'milk']]
```

It loops for each list of records `L` and checks whether there exists at least one list of rules `R` (using the built-in function [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)) such that `R` is included in `L` (using the set method [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `list` of `sets` of rules and demand that any rule [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)'ed with a inner list is identical to the `set` (i.e. *all* items in the set are also present in the inner list):

```
records = [['eggs', 'milk', 'butter'], ['ham', 'spam', 'milk'], ['cereal', 'skittles']]

list_of_rules = [{'milk', 'eggs'}, {'milk','ham'}]

# this list comprehension only filters for exact matches

# take the full inner list if all things in any rule are in this inner list
results = [ x for x in records if any( p.intersection(x) == p for p in list_of_rules)  
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[['eggs', 'milk', 'butter'], ['ham', 'spam', 'milk']]
```